# Hapi.js 17.xx: How to return response from handler function without returning

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

In Hapi.js 17.xx, how would you return a response from Hapi.js handler function, without returning that response from the handler function directly?

Rather than:

```
handlerFunction(req, h) {
  return h.response(true).code(200)
}
```

Can you do something like:

```
function callSomeFunction(req, h) {
  // Do something and then use req or h to return a response and close the request?
}

handlerFunction(req, h) {
  callSomeFunction(req, h)
}
```

Comment: handlerFunction doesn't have to return the value, it can also return a promise that will eventually resolve with the value.

Comment: I know you can. I’d like to return a response by calling a method on the response object and NOT return anything from the handler function itself. Similarly to how express can do res.send()

Comment: I see, hapi <17 worked that way, but 17 is all async and is going to force you to use promises or async/await (which is a good thing).  Is `return <something>` that much different than `res.send(<something>)`?

Comment: @Gangstead I've been looking at RXJS on the backend for some special use cases and in order to send a response from within an observable, I'd need to be able to call a method on a response object as I can't return from an observable callback. Other than trying to do that, no, returning is perfectly fine and works for everything else quite nicely :)

Comment: Create and return a promise in the handler.  Resolve that promise in the observable.

Comment: Or does returning observable [toPromise](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md) work?